# How would the bite of a venomous non-magical snake be treated in the Wizarding World?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, potions

In an original writing by Rowling on illness and disabilities in the [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability), the author states:

> I decided that, broadly speaking, wizards would have the power to correct or override ‘mundane’ nature, but not ‘magical’ nature. Therefore, a wizard could catch anything a Muggle might catch, but he could cure all of it; he would also comfortably survive a scorpion sting that might kill a Muggle, whereas he might die if bitten by a Venomous Tentacula.

Has the topic of the venom of non-magical snakes ever been tackled by Rowling in-verse or out? The page linked above (from WizardingWorld.com) doesn't mention non-magical snakes or the affect their venom would have on witches and wizards, though it does suggest that such a thing could be easily managed (*which in itself seems to suggest, at least to me, that the venom of a 'mundane' creature would affect a witch/wizard off the bat*), as I'm assuming that non-magical venomous snakes would be considered *'mundane'* in nature. I've found nothing in my research thus far that mentions it, conjecture on Reddit that I've skimmed through thus far included.

Regardless of whether or not there's canon information on the effect of non-magical snake venom on wizardkind: Is it anywhere, in canon, in an interview with Rowling, on Twitter, etc. specified *how* a witch/wizard would go about correcting or overriding the effects of snake venom or a scorpion sting? In the *'Muggle World'*, we have both antivenoms and other methods for curing snake bites and scorpion stings, but I'd like to know what methods, if any be known or can be inferred, the Wizarding World uses to combat *'mundane'* venoms. Are there specific known potions or spells that could eradicate things like snake venom from the body?

Comment: They'd just magic the person better.

Comment: @Valorum You seem to have a habit of cheekily hand-waving “magnifying” questions about Potterverse that I can’t help but find amusing.

Comment: Note that anti-venom potions are *specifically* mentioned in OotP, but prove ineffective against Nagini's *magical* venom.

Comment: I mean the answer is in your question *"would also comfortably survive a scorpion sting that might kill a Muggle"*. So assuming that they would also survive venomous snakes.

Comment: @MooNieu It doesn't hurt (regarding Valorum's amusing drive by comments) that Rowling did such a lousy job of world building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There are venom antidote potions.

Snape, the Potions professor at Hogwarts, assigns his class to write an essay on the various types of venom antidotes. His class covers potions, so the venom antidotes he teaches would also presumably be different types of potions.

> “Snape reached the front of the class and turned to face them.
>
> ‘The general standard of this homework was abysmal. Most of you would have failed had this been your examination. I expect to see a great deal more effort for this week’s essay on the various varieties of venom antidotes, or I shall have to start handing out detentions to those dunces who get a “D”.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 15 (The Hogwarts High Inquisitor)*</sup></sub>

Harry, Ron, and Hermione have to look up ingredients for Snape, and Harry looks in a book titled “Asiatic Anti-Venoms”. This means there are at least enough anti-venoms for the information about them to merit an entire book.

> “He pretended to be perusing a page of *Asiatic Anti-Venoms*, because he did not want to say what was in his mind.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 16 (At the Hog’s Head)*</sup></sub>

None of them are specifically stated to work on snake venom, but it seems highly likely that with several different anti-venoms, some would work on non-magical snake venom. Healers at St Mungo’s were able to find an antidote to venom from Nagini, a magical Horcrux snake controlled by Voldemort, which is almost certainly harder to counteract than non-magical snake venom.

> “Yes, isn’t it?’ said Mrs Weasley, leading her husband forward to a chair. ‘Healer Smethwyck worked his magic in the end, found an antidote to whatever that snake’s got in its fangs, and Arthur’s learned his lesson about dabbling in Muggle medicine, haven’t you, dear?’ she added, rather menacingly.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24 (Occlumency)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, it seems almost certain that there are antidote potions that would work on non-magical snake venom.

Answer (score 1):

Snake venom is a toxin or poison.  As such, we have a fairly definitive answer:

> Just shove a Bezoar down their throat
>     <sup>~Potion Master Severus Snape, Half-Blood Prince</sup>

As we are told in Harry's first-ever Potions lesson:

> A bezoar is a stone taken from the stomach of a goat and it will save you from most poisons.
>   <sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's stone</sup>

Comment: Snake venom is decidedly *not* a poison, though. A toxin, yes, but I don’t see toxins specified in your quotes. Some animals are poisonous and other are venomous. There is a very distinct difference between the two. Do you have any canon evidence that bezoars counteract non-magical venom in general?

Comment: Bezoar is an option for poisons as @MooNieu says, but while it works in most cases it wasn't the only (or best) option.